# How do I join with the latest update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:

1. `delivery` with columns `uid`, `dtime`, `candy` which records which candy was given to which user when
2. `lookup` with columns `uid` and `ltime` which records when the user's pocket was examined

I need to know the result of the `lookup`, i.e., the result table should have columns `uid`, `ltime`, `candy`, telling me what was found in the user's pocket (assume the user eats the old candy when given the new one).

There were several deliveries before each lookup.
I need only the latest one.

E.g.,

```
select l.uid, l.ltime, 
       d.candy  /* ... for max(d.dtime):
          IOW, I want to sort (d.dtime, d.candy) 
          by the first field in decreasing order, 
          then take the second field in the first element */
from delivery d
join lookup l 
on d.uid = l.uid
and d.dtime <= l.ltime
group by l.uid, l.ltime
```

So, how do I know what was found by the lookup?

Comment: Updated my answer to add time.  Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Top 1 with Ties to get latest delivery and Join back to the Lookup Table

```
Select * from lookup
    Inner Join (
        Select Top 1  with Ties uid,dtime
          From delivery 
          Order by row_number() over (partition by uid order by dtime desc)) as Delivery
          on lookup.uid = Delivery.uid  and lookup.ltime >= delivery.dtime
```

Comment: how is your answer better than the other one?

Comment: @sds . . . I don't even see how this one would work, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Gordon The Top 1 with Ties ordering by Row_number gives you a set of the Latest  Deliveries and then you just Inner Join to that Derived Table.

Comment: @Dobbins . . . Oh, I see.  Because of the weird use of `row_number()` in the `order by`.  I see how it works.  Although I agree with sds, it is clever.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `outer apply`:

```
select l.*, d.candy
from lookup l outer apply
     (select top 1 d.*
      from delivery d
      where d.uid = l.uid and d.dtime <= l.ltime
      order by d.dtime desc
     ) d;
```

That answers your question.  But, wouldn't the user have *all* the candies since the last lookup?  Or, are we assuming that the user eats the candy on hand when the user is given another?  Perhaps the pocket only holds one candy.

Comment: I got a great laugh from "the pocket only holds one candy". Thank you!

Comment: well, "the pocket only holds one candy" _is_ the condition, please see the edit. Thanks!